# How to minimize my big query for showing counts using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am taking counts from CTE but common is Status(working,pening) and Divisions
but my query is becoming big because left join is same but just status and division are different. I have wrote 10 left join count but by passing status and divisions.

Below is my whole sql query

```
declare @createdBy int=79

;with cte as (                
select max(w.WorkingNo)WorkingNo 
from                
working w 
join workingdealhistory wd on wd.WorkHistoryId=w.workingNo and 
w.status  IN ('WORKING','PENDING')     and w.mhlId>0  and w.IsActive=1
join TreasureTrove t on t.CandidateId=w.CandidateId and t.DepartmentId=2
group by w.CandidateId,w.status                
)   

select distinct m.potentialHospitalNo 
,m.hospital                       
,ph.clientname
,cdiwr.working cdiworking
,cdipn.pending cdipending
,himwr.working himworking
,himpn.pending himpending
,cmurwr.working cmurworking
,cmurpn.pending cmurpending                 
,odmwr.working odmworking
,odmpn.pending odmpending                   
,traumawr.working traumaworking
,traumapn.pending traumapending
,ph.ClientId
from PotentialHospitlMaster m (NOLOCK)
Inner JOIN HospitalStatus HS (NOLOCK) On m.potentialHospitalNo=HS.ClientId
inner join potentialhospital ph on ph.potentialhospitalno=m.potentialhospitalno
          
    --this is status='working' and division='CDI'         
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)working, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='working' and wh.Division='CDI' group by w.MHLId) as cdiwr on cdiwr.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

    --this is status='pending' and division='CDI'   
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)pending, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='pending' and wh.Division='CDI' group by w.MHLId) as cdipn on cdipn.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

    --this is status='working' and division='HIM'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)working, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='working' and wh.Division='HIM' group by w.MHLId) as himwr on himwr.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

  --this is status='pending' and division='HIM'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)pending, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='pending' and wh.Division='HIM' group by w.MHLId) as himpn on himpn.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo                     

--this is status='working' and division='CMUR'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)working, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='working' and wh.Division='CMUR' group by w.MHLId) as cmurwr on cmurwr.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

--this is status='pending' and division='CMUR'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)pending, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='pending' and wh.Division='CMUR' group by w.MHLId) as cmurpn on cmurpn.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo                      

--this is status='working' and division='ODM'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)working, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='working' and wh.Division='ODM' group by w.MHLId) as odmwr on odmwr.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

--this is status='pending' and division='ODM'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)pending, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='pending' and wh.Division='ODM' group by w.MHLId) as odmpn on odmpn.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo                         

--this is status='working' and division='Trauma'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)working, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='working' and wh.Division='Trauma' group by w.MHLId) as traumawr on traumawr.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

--this is status='pending' and division='Trauma'
LEFT join(select COUNT(w.WorkingNo)pending, MHLId from cte c inner join
working w on w.WorkingNo=c.WorkingNo 
inner join WorkingDealHistory WH on w.WorkingNo=WH.WorkHistoryId                         
inner join potentialhospital phs on phs.potentialHospitalNo=w.MHLId where w.Status='pending' and wh.Division='Trauma' group by w.MHLId) as traumapn on traumapn.MHLId=ph.potentialHospitalNo 

where  m.IsActive=1 and HS.UpdatedStatus='MSA Sent' and HS.CreatedBy=@createdBy
```

Is there anything which we can minimize query by using group by or anything.

Comment: You can probably simplify this to one query of aggregates using conditional aggregates, e.g. `COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'Working' AND wh.Division = 'CDI' THEN 1 END) AS CDIWorking, COUNT(CASE WHEN w.status = 'Pending' AND wh.Division = 'HIM' THEN 1 END) AS HIMPending, ` and so on. I can't suggest a full query I am afraid as I really don't understand your current query, or what purpose you think your current cte serves.

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) alert! If you see you are repeating an almost identical query then stop. This should be a single join with conditional aggregation.

Comment: single left join how this case happend confused agian. @GarethD

Comment: i am using cte data with left join can you post your answer. @Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a bit of a stab at your schema, and I think you could do it with something like:

```
DECLARE @createdBy INT = 79;

WITH cte AS
(                
    SELECT  w.CandidateId, w.status, WorkingNo = MAX(w.WorkingNo)
    FROM    working AS w
            JOIN workingdealhistory AS wd
                ON  wd.WorkHistoryId = w.workingNo
                AND w.status IN ('WORKING', 'PENDING')
                AND w.mhlId > 0
                AND w.IsActive = 1
            JOIN TreasureTrove AS t
                ON  t.CandidateId = w.CandidateId
                AND t.DepartmentId = 2
    GROUP BY
            w.CandidateId, w.status;              
)   
SELECT  DISTINCT
        m.potentialHospitalNo,
        m.hospital,
        ph.clientname,
        cnt.CDIworking,
        cnt.CDIPending,
        cnt.HIMworking,
        cnt.HIMPending,
        cnt.CMURworking,
        cnt.CMURPending,
        cnt.ODMworking,
        cnt.ODMPending,
        cnt.Traumaworking,
        cnt.TraumaPending
        ph.ClientId
FROM    PotentialHospitlMaster AS m
        INNER JOIN HospitalStatus AS HS
            ON m.potentialHospitalNo = HS.ClientId
        INNER JOIN potentialhospital AS ph
            ON ph.potentialhospitalno = m.potentialhospitalno   
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  w.MHLId,
                    CDIworking = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'working' AND wh.Division = 'CDI' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    CDIPending = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'pending' AND wh.Division = 'CDI' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    HIMworking = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'working' AND wh.Division = 'HIM' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    HIMPending = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'pending' AND wh.Division = 'HIM' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    CMURworking = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'working' AND wh.Division = 'CMUR' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    CMURPending = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'pending' AND wh.Division = 'CMUR' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    ODMworking = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'working' AND wh.Division = 'ODM' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    ODMPending = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'pending' AND wh.Division = 'ODM' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    Traumaworking = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'working' AND wh.Division = 'Trauma' THEN w.WorkingNo END),
                    TraumaPending = COUNT(CASE WHEN w.Status = 'pending' AND wh.Division = 'Trauma' THEN w.WorkingNo END)
            FROM    working AS w
                    INNER JOIN WorkingDealHistory AS wh
                        ON w.WorkingNo = wh.WorkHistoryId
                    INNER JOIN cte AS c
                        ON c.CandidateId = w.CandidateId
                        AND c.status = w.status
                        AND c.WorkingNo = w.WorkingNo
            GROUP BY
                    w.MHLId
        ) AS cnt
            ON cnt.MHLId = ph.potentialHospitalNo
WHERE   m.IsActive = 1
AND     HS.UpdatedStatus = 'MSA Sent'
AND     HS.CreatedBy = @createdBy;
```

N.B. I've removed `NOLOCK` as putting this everywhere is a [bad habit to kick](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Also, I am deeply suspicious of most queries that use `DISTINCT` across a large number of columns like this. More often than not the duplicates are a symptom of an error with the query, and `DISTINCT` is just a nasty plaster trying to cover up the real issue. You should work out where duplicates are coming from and look to remove either early or at least in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: Are you not included cte query because that are top records? i have to include cte query with the above yours answer?. @GarethD

Comment: To be honest I struggled to work out exactly what you are trying to achieve with your CTE as I don't fully understand your schema, so I left it out. I've modified the query above slightly, but it may not be exactly what you need, but hopefully gives you a good enough start for a way to get a number of different counts without repeating the same query over and over again

Comment: Agenda of cte is to take max workingno because multiple working will inserting of same id need to take max workingno data, if keep cte and base cte can you update answer will help more. @GarethD

Comment: Your answer is very helpful thanks can please post by using cte will good for me. @GarethD

Comment: okay i am accepting you answer because you almost given idea to achieve thanks sir. @GarethD